# Auto checker of application that is running and create a report

Tags: c#, window

I would like to create an application that will check if the schedule task program is running, and after checking it will generate a report and auto send report to email.

This is for monitoring purposes. And to track the discrepancies in the system.

Hoping for your response.

Best Regards,

Comment: You can do it..! What is the response u want here?

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not good in win form apps. I appreciate your response. I would like to ask I you have some reference that I can read on.Thank you.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses%28v=vs.71%29.aspx. Use some timer to get the process status and make a report and send through MailMessage.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a timer
- In the timer's elaspsed function, get all running processes
- check by process name (or what ever) and see if it exists;
- Write an email with System.Web.Mail.MailMessage class

Answer (score 0):

This is like a reference code for you, modify it as you need:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateTimer();
        }

        private void CreateTimer()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer ProcessChecker = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            ProcessChecker.Tick += new System.EventHandler(ProcessChecker_Tick);
            ProcessChecker.Interval = 6000;    //set your required interval for checking
            ProcessChecker.Start(); //now start the timer            
        }

        void ProcessChecker_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] pro = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"); //place your processname at the place of notepad
            if (pro.Length > 0)
            {
                new Thread(GenerateReport).Start(); //it will generate report in parallel so your process will not be effected by its longer time to generate report and sending email
            }
        }

        private void GenerateReport()
        {
            //after generating report send email
            SendEmail();  //create it and then invoke it here
        }
```